# What is the book that Emile Hirsch reads in "Into the Wild"?

Tags: analysis, character, into-the-wild

In the film [Into the Wild](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Into_the_Wild_%28film%29), Emile Hirsch keeps on reading a book at different times, such as night time. In some scenes, the cover of the book is slightly visible.

What was the book he was reading?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can spot him *reading* a few different books:

- **Family happiness** (*Leo Tolstoy*)
- **The Call of the Wild** (*Jack London*)
- **Doctor Zhivago** (*Boris Pasternak*)

and, of course,

- **Tanaina plantlore, Dena'ina k'et'una** (*Priscilla Russell Kari*)

In the movie You can also see the entire book collection is carrying (at about minute 20), featuring:

- **War and Peace** (*Leo Tolstoy*)
- **Death of Ivan Ilych** (*Leo Tolstoy*)
- **The Call of the Wild** (*Jack London*) [that I already cited]
- **White Fang** (*Jack London*)
- **Taras Bulba** (*Nicolai Gogol*)
- **Walden** (*Henry David Thoreau*)
- **The Spectator Bird** (*Stegner*)
- **Doctor Zhivago** (*Boris Pasternak*) [that I already cited]
- **Family Happiness** (*Leo Tolstoy*) [that I already cited]

According to the Krakauer's book, "Supertramp" was also carrying:

- **Crime and Punishment** (*Fyodor Dostoyevsky*)
- **Education of a Wandering Man** (*Louis L'Amour*)
- **Moon-Face** (*Jack London*)
- **Brown Wolf** (*Jack London*)
- **To Build a Fire** (*Jack London*)
- **Terminal Man** (*Michael Crichton*)
- **O Jersualem!** (*Larry Collins & Dominique Lapierre*)

---

Hope this helps.